# If I add mp3 to raw folder, don't create R.java

Tags: android, eclipse, multimedia

I have Android project (I use Eclipse and ADT plugin). I created the `res/raw` folder and put into `loop-searched.mp3`.

File `R.java` was not changed and if I remove R.java, it not recreated. Why?

Comment: Do you have any error in any file?

Comment: No, project compile if I don't have mp3 file. If I add file to raw, R.java not recreated.

Comment: I try clean project but nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Filename loop-searched.mp3 contains illegal char "-". I change it to "_". Filename must contains only letters and digits such to could be a identifier.